# Can you help me to understand how という is used?

Tags: meaning

I recently came across the following sentence:

> 他人が悪い事をしているからといって自分もそうしてよい**という**ことにはならない。

I understand the sentence. It means that if other people do bad things and you also do bad things, it doesn't become a good thing (i.e. two wrongs don't make a right.)

However, I don't understand what という means, and what purpose it serves in the sentence.

I know that という can be used to refer to the name of something.

For example: これはというスマトフォン。（This is called a smartphone.)

What does it mean in the first sentence I gave?

Comment: 「これはというスマートフォン」, believe it or not, simply means "a very good Smartphone".  It is not even a sentence.  It does not mean "This is called a Smartphone".

Comment: Okay thanks. But that doesn't really help me understand it. Maybe you can give an example?

Comment: @Bobby I think what you wrote is like 「これは」というスマートフォン (=優秀なスマートフォン), which is a noun phrase.  But I think you wanted to write the more basic sentence これはスマートフォンと言う, with the verb and particle at the end.  I think you just stuck という in the wrong place :-)

Comment: Gotcha. Just another question. Why is putting という in front equivalent to 優秀な in the explanation you gave? Is it a set phrase

Comment: @Bobby I'm not sure I can do a good job explaining it, but [これは can be an exclamation expressing surprise/admiration](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF), so imagine a smartphone that makes you say これは！  If you post a separate question about it, someone might write a better answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [many ways](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/52678/m0u/) 「という」 works, but in this type of sentence, I think you can voice it as the word `that`.

Although you understand the meaning of the sentence correctly, your literal translation leads me to suspect you are parsing it incorrectly. (I'm sorry if that's not the case.)

### X からといって Y ということにはならない

This is a frequently used construct in the form 「X からといって Y ということにはならない」. Remember that `ことになる` here can be voiced as `make it fact`. So `ことにならない` is `doesn't make it fact`. And notice that the `といって` is also a form of `という`.

> X ←[ から(because) ][ といって(that) ]　Y←[ という(that) ][ ことにはならない(doesn't make it fact) ]

Reorder the words, and you get “Because that X, doesn't make it fact that Y”. (= Just because X is true, doesn't mean that Y is true)

Now, take the translations of 「他人が悪い事をしている (Other people are doing bad things)」「自分もそうしてよい (It is fine for one to do so also)」, and insert them in as the X and Y. This procedure will work for other sentences in this format (e.g. 「**自分ができない**からといって、**あきらめていい**ということにはならない」「**値段{ねだん}が高い**からといって、**おいしい**ということにはならない」).

### Similar uses of という

Maybe visualize it as a pointer:

- 王子が結婚した という(→) ニュース (news ← that is "the prince married")
- 彼が生きている という(→) うわさ (rumor ← that is "he is alive")
- コーヒーが飲みたい という(→) 気持ち (feeling ← that is "wanting to drink coffee")
- iPhone 6 という(→) スマートフォン (smartphone ← that is "iPhone 6")
- 女性が多い という(→) 情報 (information ← that is "there are many women")

---

Using this pointer image, maybe you can also visualize 「これは X という (This is called X)」 reordered, as:

> X という(→) これ (this ← that is "X")

Hope that helps in some way.